# How to tell if DocuSign signer failed security check? (API)

Tags: docusignapi

We send some DocuSign envelopes via email and we can't find anything in the API that will tell us if a signer failed security check. The envelope status stays in 'sent'.

The docs do not mention any status that would correspond to failed security check: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/appendix/status_and_error_codes.html#envelope--recipient-status-codes

Comment: RECIPIENT_HAS_FAILED_SECURITY_CHECK is returned when that event occurs, https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#Error%20Code/Error%20Codes%20and%20Associated%20Messages.htm%3FTocPath%3DError%2520Code%2520Information|_____1

Comment: If we do in-browser DocuSign, then yes, we get RECIPIENT_HAS_FAILED_SECURITY_CHECK. But if we send it via email, it's asynchronous, we don't get any notifications on failure. I will try to get the recipient status and see if there's anything there.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Connect to receive status events?  You can have it tell you when there's an Authentication Failure.  Here's what comes through when that happens.  You're right the Envelope status stays Sent.  The Failure is noted lower down.  I imagine you'd get the same if you called the API to get envelope status directly.

```
<EnvelopeStatus>
        <RecipientStatuses>
            <RecipientStatus>
                <Type>Signer</Type>
                <Email>XXXXX</Email>
                <UserName>John Q Signer</UserName>
                <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
                <Sent>2014-12-30T07:29:45.747</Sent>
                <DeclineReason xsi:nil="true" />
                <Status>Sent</Status>  <!-- STILL SENT -->
                <RecipientIPAddress />
                <IDCheckInformation />
                <RecipientAuthenticationStatus>
                    <IDQuestionsResult>
                        <Status>Failed</Status>  <!-- HERE IS THE FAILURE -->
                        <EventTimestamp>2014-12-30T13:30:09.79Z</EventTimestamp>
                    </IDQuestionsResult>
                    <IDLookupResult>
                        <Status>Passed</Status>
                        <EventTimestamp>2014-12-30T13:30:09.79Z</EventTimestamp>
                    </IDLookupResult>
                </RecipientAuthenticationStatus>
```

Comment: Any idea why <RecipientAuthenticationStatus/> would be empty?