# DocuSign Connect how to configure envelope to receive notifications on authentication failure?

Tags: c#, docusignapi, webhooks, docusignconnect

I am trying to manage authentication failed cases in my app. I have successfully established DocuSign Connect communication and receive notifications from DocuSign when envelopes are Completed or Voided. But now I have a case when fail Authentication (exemple wrong code entered 3 times on SMS authentication). In this case the envelope is locked for the signer. I would like to be able to send notification to custommer service when this happens.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848717/how-to-tell-if-docusign-signer-failed-security-check-api) it is possible to get this information in a DocuSign Connect notification but I receive none.

In my case I configure notifications per envelope through the API (not a global account configuration) like follows (C#):

```
envelope.EventNotification = new EventNotification()
{
    Url = _webhookUrl,
    RequireAcknowledgment = "true",
    LoggingEnabled = "true",
    IncludeEnvelopeVoidReason = "true",
    IncludeDocuments = "false",
    IncludeCertificateOfCompletion = "false",
    IncludeCertificateWithSoap = "false",
    IncludeDocumentFields = "false",
    IncludeHMAC = "true",
    IncludeSenderAccountAsCustomField = "false",
    IncludeTimeZone = "true",
    UseSoapInterface = "false",
    EnvelopeEvents = new List<EnvelopeEvent>() {
        new EnvelopeEvent("Draft"),
        new EnvelopeEvent("Sent"),
        new EnvelopeEvent("Delivered"),
        new EnvelopeEvent("Completed"),
        new EnvelopeEvent("Declined"),
        new EnvelopeEvent("Voided") 
    },
    RecipientEvents = new List<RecipientEvent>() {
        new RecipientEvent(null, "Draft" ),
        new RecipientEvent(null, "Sent" ),
        new RecipientEvent(null, "Delivered" ),
        new RecipientEvent(null, "Completed" ),
        new RecipientEvent(null, "Voided" )
    }
};
```

Edit:
I found that when creating a global configuration in administrator interface there is an extra possible event option "Authentication failed" seems like thats exactly what I need!

[image]

But what is the value to provide with the API???

This option is not even documented in support center https://support.docusign.com/guides/dfs-admin-guide-envelope-recipient-events-ref

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I "almost" found the answer in swagger specs (available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docusign/eSign-OpenAPI-Specification/master/esignature.rest.swagger-v2.1.json)) that there are AuthenticationFailed and AutoResponded recipient events. And yes by adding AuthenticationFailed I get a webhook call whe SMS authentication fails.
So my final event notification configuration looks like follows:

```
envelope.EventNotification = new EventNotification()
{
    Url = _webhookUrl,
    RequireAcknowledgment = "true",
    LoggingEnabled = "true",
    IncludeEnvelopeVoidReason = "true",
    IncludeDocuments = "false",
    IncludeCertificateOfCompletion = "false",
    IncludeCertificateWithSoap = "false",
    IncludeDocumentFields = "false",
    IncludeHMAC = "true",
    IncludeSenderAccountAsCustomField = "false",
    IncludeTimeZone = "true",
    UseSoapInterface = "false",
    EnvelopeEvents = new List<EnvelopeEvent>() { 
        new EnvelopeEvent("Completed"), 
        new EnvelopeEvent("Declined"), 
        new EnvelopeEvent("Voided") 
    },
    RecipientEvents = new List<RecipientEvent>() { 
        new RecipientEvent(null, "AuthenticationFailed"), 
        new RecipientEvent(null, "Completed"), 
        new RecipientEvent(null, "Declined")
    }
};
```

Unfortunatly the portions of the documentation related to Connect are very light! Many parameters are not explained.

**After more testing it is still not working.** Actually I get the notification but the envelope status is "sent" and the `<RecipientAuthenticationStatus />` is empty. And I have no way to determin an authentication error occured.

Answer (score 0):

Bug case was created back in June (CONNECT-1845) and our engineers are currently working to resolve the issue